# babel-polyfill Error on Gravity Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a page with a gravity forms injected and as soon as the user tries to submit an exception is given for

> jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 Uncaught Error: only one instance of
>   babel-polyfill is allowed

Did someone experience the same issue ? How can I get rid of such error ?